# disable access to Laravel API from browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

How can I restrict direct access on GET route?

example localhost/api/helloworld

if I send a request with postman I want to get a response, but if I try open URL in a browser I need redirect to the homepage or give some 403 error?

should I use some header to restrict it or there is another way to do it in Laravel?

Comment: You can create a middleware in laravel and add one new parameter in header and check in middleware. If that parameter get then give access otherwise restrict.

Comment: I was thinking you could look for `content-type: application/json` in the request headers (Postman can set this, as can all good HTTP clients), but the browser is unlikely to set that header by default. Otherwise another request header token per @LuckySaini suggestion would work.

Comment: There are two nice example on how you _can_ do it but please do reconsider why you want to do this. I for one really like looking at api's in my browser to see what results I can expect.

Comment: You can check for the token and authenticate it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is use token. Laravel provides you API authentication, follow this link [API Authentication (Passport)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport)

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to detect the requesting client from headers.

```
public function isBrowserRequest()
{
  $browsers = ['Opera', 'Mozilla', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Edge'];

  $userAgent = request()->header('User-Agent');

  $isBrowser = false;

  foreach($browsers as $browser){
    if(strpos($userAgent, $browser) !==  false){
      $isBrowser = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return ['result' => $isBrowser];
}
```